# Nested IIf statements work but Switch statements produce an 'Overflow' error in MS Access. Why?

Tags: ms-access, switch-statement, iif

The query I'm working on displays the percentage of an insurance policy cost in regards to general income of a person.

The nested IIf approach:

```
percentage: IIf([general_income]=0,"No income",
IIf(IsNull([PolicyValue]),"No policy",
IIf([PolicyValue]>[general_income],"Error",
Format([PolicyValue]/[general_income],"Percent"))))
```

The Switch approach:

```
percentage: Switch(
[general_income]=0,"No income",
IsNull([PolicyValue]),"No policy",
[PolicyValue]>[general_income],"Error",
True,Format([PolicyValue]/[general_income],"Percent")
)
```

My initial approach was the Switch method and while debugging I assumed the Overflow error was caused by a division by zero because various other posts on this topic pointed there and also in my case, when dividing a random number(e.g. 1) by `general_income` Division by zero took the place of the Overflow error.

However, I do not see how `general_income` could ever be 0 given that the first case takes care of that. Any ideas on what caused the Overflow error in the Switch scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Switch Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379):

> Switch evaluates **all** of the expressions, even though it returns
>   only one of them. For this reason, you should watch for undesirable
>   side effects. For example, if the evaluation of any expression results
>   in a division by zero error, an error occurs.

So the first case does not take care of the fact that `general_income` could be 0 and then `[PolicyValue]/[general_income]` throws the error.